# Factor of 1/2 on the cross-product of vectors

Tags: vectors, cross-product

I was trying to derive the cross-product of vectors:

$\vec{B} = B_\theta$

$\vec{J} = -\frac{1}{\mu_0} \frac{d}{dr}B_z(r)$

substituted on

$$\nabla p = \vec{J} \times \vec{B}$$

getting

$$\frac{d}{dr}\Bigg(p+\frac{B_\theta ^2}{\mu_0}\Bigg) + \frac{B^2_\theta}{\mu_0 r} = 0$$

but the text says it is

$$\frac{d}{dr}\Bigg(p+\frac{B_\theta^2}{2\mu_0}\Bigg) + \frac{B^2_\theta}{\mu_0 r} = 0$$

Where does the 1/2 factor come from in term 2?

Thanks!

Comment: Note that we have

$$B_\theta\frac{dB_\theta}{dr}=\frac12\frac{dB^2_\theta}{dr}$$

Comment: Ohhhh thanks!!!

Comment: You're welcome!  My pleasure.